# Find the count of a particular number in an infinite stream of numbers at a particular moment

Tags: algorithm, memory, data-structures, stream, distributed-computing

I faced this problem in a recent interview:

You have a stream of incoming numbers in range `0 to 60000` and you have a function which will take a number from that range and return the count of occurrence of that number till that moment. Give a suitable Data structure/algorithm to implement this system.

My solution is:

Make an array of size 60001 pointing to bit-vectors. These bit vectors will contain the count of the incoming numbers and the incoming numbers will also be used to index into the array for the corresponding number. Bit-vectors will dynamically increase as the count gets too big to hold in them.

So, if the numbers are coming at rate `100numbers/sec` then, in 1million years total numbers will be = `(100*3600*24)*365*1000000 = 3.2*10^15`. In the worst case where all numbers in the stream is same it will take `ceil((log(3.2*10^15) / log 2) )= 52bits` and if the numbers are uniformly distributed the we will have `(3.2*10^15) / 60001 = 5.33*10^10` number of occurrences for each number which will require total of `36 bits` for each numbers.
So, assuming 4byte pointers we need `(60001 * 4)/1024 = 234 KB` memory for the array and for the case with same numbers, we need bit vector size = `52/8 = 7.5 bytes` which is still around 234KB. And for the other case we need `(60001 * 36 / 8)/1024 = 263.7 KB` for bit vector totaling about 500KB. So, it is very much feasible to do this with ordinary PC and memory.

But the interviewer said, as it is infinite stream it will eventually overflow and gave me hint like how can we do this if there were many PCs and we could pass messages between them or think about file system etc. But I kept thinking if this solution was not working then, others would too. Needless to say, I did not get the job.

How to do this problem with less memory? Can you think of an alternative approach (using network of PCs may be)?

Comment: Unless "many PCs" means you could add more as needed, I don't see how this is better in combating infinity than one.

Comment: Agreed with you about this solution. The infinite stream of data can't be stored in the finite memory how even refined algorithm could be. You don't need in this hirer.

Comment: you were right and he was wrong. few megabytes will last you for 10^100 numbers i.e. eternity, you don't need more than that. Maybe they wanted to see how you would argue your case, how convinced you were that you were right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A formal model for the problem could be the following.

We want to know if it exists a constant space bounded Turing machine such that, in any given time it recognizes the language L of all couples (number,number of occurrences so far). This means that all correct couples will be accepted and all incorrect couples will be rejected.

As a corollary of the Theorem 3.13 in Hopcroft-Ullman we know that **every language recognized by a constant space bounded machine is regular**.

It can be proven by using the pumping lemma for regular languages that the language described above is not a regular language. So you can't recognize it with a constant space bounded machine.

Comment: the difference between theory and engineering is that in theory 10^100 is a very small number compared to infinity, but in  engineering `10^100` *is* infinity.

Comment: @WillNess I guess that depends on the problem that you are going to solve. But if someone has given a proof that something is impossible even theoretically, I would't attempt to realize it in practice! :)

Comment: On the contrary, something that's proven to be impossible for infinite case, is quite possible for 10^100. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use index based search, by using an array like int arr[60000][1], whenever you get a number , say 5000, directly access the index( num-1) = (5000-1) as, arr[num-1][1], and increment the number, and now whenever u want to know how many times a particular num has ocurred you can just access it by arr[num-1][1] and you'll get the count for that number, Its simplest possible linear time implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this [External Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_merge)? Store the infinite stream in a file. Do a seek() (`RandomAccessFile.seek()` in Java) in the file and get to the appropriate timestamp. This is similar to Binary Search since the data is sorted by timestamps. Once you get to the appropriate timestamp, the problem turns into counting a particular number from an infinite set of numbers. Here, instead of doing a quick sort in memory, Counting sort can be done since the range of numbers is limited.

Comment: No job for you either.  If the interviewer clings to the infinity of the stream of numbers, where are you going to get the infinite array of disks for the file you hypothesise into existence.  That'll be RAID-aleph-null I expect.

Comment: Wow!! Isn't file system infinite compared to memory? And moreover, it is the interviewer who mentioned filesystem as a hint which is clearly mentioned in the question.